Docker Laravel Jenkins Testing
Our builds have been working flawlessly for years now but last week our testing stage stopped working. I cant understand why because the docker image, jenkins etc remained unchanged. Something came into play regarding Certificates and is now blocking the whole process.
This is the error we are getting. It seems to be within the core laravel package but im not sure. Im trying to find a way around the issue so testing can continue.

[2024-12-17T14:38:27.360Z] + php artisan migrate '--env=testing' --seed

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z] 

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]    INFO  Preparing database.  

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z] 

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]   Creating migration table ....................................... 8.87ms DONE

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z] 

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]    INFO  Loading stored database schemas.  

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z] 

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]   database/schema/mysql-schema.sql .............................. 53.00ms FAIL

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z] 

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z] In Process.php line 270:

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]                                                                                

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]   The command "mysql  --user="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_USER}" --password="${:LARAVEL_L  

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]   OAD_PASSWORD}" --host="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_HOST}" --port="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_PORT}  

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]   " --database="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_DATABASE}" < "${:LARAVEL_LOAD_PATH}"" failed.  

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]                                                                                

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]   Exit Code: 1(General error)                                                  

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]                                                                                

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]   Working directory: /home/ubuntu/workspace/digital-dealership_jenkins_test    

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]                                                                                

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]   Output:                                                                      

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]   ================                                                             

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]                                                                                

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]                                                                                

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]   Error Output:                                                                

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]   ================                                                             

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]   mysql: Deprecated program name. It will be removed in a future release, use  

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]    '/usr/bin/mariadb' instead                                                  

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]   ERROR 2026 (HY000): TLS/SSL error: self-signed certificate in certificate c  

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]   hain                                                                         

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z]                                                                                

[2024-12-17T14:38:28.379Z] 

script returned exit code 1


Based on the deprecation warning, you use mariadb, not mysql. I corrected the tags.

Otherwise, this seems to be a DBA issue, not a progtamming one. Your DBA configured your mariadb instance not to trust self-signed certificates. Correct that and you will be fine. But the deprecation warning will cause you some problems if laravel keeps considering mariadb the same as mysql and mariadb does remove mysql as command line client from its distributions.

@Shadow thank you. We use mysql but this is used for testing and i cant recall why now. RUN if [ "$APP_ENV" = "local" ] || [ "$APP_ENV" = "testing" ]; then \   apk add --no-cache mysql-client mariadb-connector-c; \ fi

Then your test environment does not match your production one as mysql is not going to generate a warning to rename its client to mariadb...

I suggest you use the mariadb-client. The TLS error is probably an incompatibility between mysql-client and server autotls.

Since MariaDB Server version 11.4 and MariaDB Connector/C 3.4 peer certificate verification is enabled by default.
Unless the connection is considered to be "secure" (connecting via unix_socket, 127.0.0.1 or :0:0:0:0) the client will raise an error if the peer certificate verification failed (e.g. self signed, expired, revoked, etc.)
You can disable the peer certificate verification by passing --ssl_verify_server_cert=0 to the mariadb command line client.
